# How to create modal alert using sweetalert?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am a beginner in Javascript and I need to generate an alert for the user when clicking on menu2 on my page to return a message, for this I opted to use a modal plugin compatible with all browsers[Plugin modal](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) The code below was all I could get Until now, but without success.
Here's my html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='menu'>
  <li id='menu1'><a href='/web/front/helpdesk.public.php' title="Home" class='itemP'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id='menu2'><a href='/web/front/helpdesk.public.php' title="Cria um chamado" class='itemP'>Cria um chamado</a>
  </li>
  <li id='menu3'><a href='/web/front/ticket.php' title="Chamados" class='itemP'>Chamados</a>
  </li>
  <li id='menu4'><a href='/web/front/reservationitem.php' title="Reservas" class='itemP'>Reservas</a>
  </li>
  <li id='menu5'><a href='/web/front/helpdesk.faq.php' title="FAQ" class='itemP'>FAQ</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here's my javascript

```html
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo'setTimeout(function () {
  swal
  ("Return the alert test !",
  "Message!",
  "success");';
  echo '}, 1000);
  </script>';
```

Return of the alert working on the page.

[image]

I've tried it this way, but unsuccessfully so far.

```html
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo'setTimeout(function () {
  echo '$(document).ready(function() {
  echo '$('#menu2').click(function(event) { 
  swal
  ("Return the alert test !",
  "Message!",
  "success");';
  echo '}, 1000);
  </script>';
```

Error while trying to run the solution in my php.

[image]

I do not want the method to be called, the default action of the event will not fire. To do this use event.preventDefault (); But it's not working for me. The alert does not appear. Does anyone have a solution?

```html
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
echo '    $("#menu2").click(function(event){'; 
echo '            event.preventDefault()';        
echo '        swal("Return the alert test !", "Message!", "success")';
echo '    })';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: A man does not require setTimeout() by using document.ready(). Also multiple ending brackets are missing. Check your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw jquery should look like this (properly closed functions):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu2').click(function(event){ 
        swal("Return the alert test !", "Message!")
    })
});
```

However you echo it, is up to you.
Also you do not require setTimeout() by using document.ready().

Edit:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
echo '    $("#menu2").click(function(event){';
echo '        swal("Return the alert test !", "Message!")';
echo '    })';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: I tested in NetBeans, is giving syntax error in php did not work for me.          echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu2').click(function(event){ 
        swal("Return the alert test !", "Message!")
       })
      });
      </script>';

Comment: Probably because of the single quotes around menu2. A man should not mix up different languages string delimiters.

Comment: I tested here did not solve it for me, so far I can only return the alert on the page using my example. What would be best for you to understand better?

Comment: Worked perfectly, however it disappears from the screen when loading the page.

Comment: Well, to further help a man I would require all his code behind. As a tip, just take the raw jquery code, put it in an external .js file and add it like usual to the head. So a man wont have those echo issues.

Comment: I want it to stay on the page hoping to click "OK".
Event.preventDefault ();

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
echo '    $("#menu2").click(function(event){';
echo '    event.preventDefault()';       
echo '        swal("Return the alert test !", "Message!")';
echo '    })';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129167/discussion-between-renato-lazaro-and-lain).

Comment: Your solution and understanding of the operation helped me perfectly, thank you very much for making some of your time available, to help not only me, but a great volume of people.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the modal alert [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) work by following the responses obtained here. I had a better understanding of Javascript and in specific [event.preventdefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) getting to the code below that worked perfectly for me.

```html
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu2").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      swal("Many thanks to everyone for making me a better programmer.!", "Message", "success");
    })
  });
</script>
<?php
```